# When is the carbaldehyde suffix correct?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Is benzene carbaldehyde a correct name for Benzaldehyde? I'm (always) getting confused between common and IUPAC names. If the above name is correct then is it a common one or IUPAC? And why don't we use it more often?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are IUPAC names, but used in different situations. For a 1 carbon aldehyde attached to a benzene, the one that must be used is benzaldehyde.

Aldehydes ($\ce{R-CHO}$) take the suffix "-al". If other functional groups are present, the chain is numbered such that the aldehyde carbon is in the "1" position, unless functional groups of higher precedence are present.

If a prefix form is required, "oxo-" is used (as for ketones), with the position number indicating the end of a chain: $\ce{CHOCH2COOH}$ is 3-oxopropanoic acid. If the carbon in the carbonyl group cannot be included in the attached chain (for instance in the case of cyclic aldehydes), the prefix "formyl-" or the suffix "-carbaldehyde" is used: $\ce{C6H11CHO}$ is cyclohexanecarbaldehyde. **If an aldehyde is attached to a benzene and is the main functional group, the suffix becomes benzaldehyde.**

For example, this guy would be cyclohex-2-ene-1-carbaldehyde:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Both names, ‘benzenecarbaldehyde’ and ‘benzaldehyde’, are unambiguous and describe the same compound. However, the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) is ‘benzaldehyde’.

Concerning aldehydes, the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)* reads as follows:

> **P-66.6.1** Systematic names of aldehydes
>
> Aldehydes are systematically named in three ways:
>
> (1) substitutively, using the suffixes ‘al’ for $\ce{-(C)HO}$ and ‘carbaldehyde’ for $\ce{-CHO}$;
>
> (2) by changing the ‘ic acid’ or ‘oic acid’ endings of retained names of carboxylic acids into ‘aldehyde’; the nomenclatural properties of acids are transferred to aldehydes; thus, preferred names of aldehydes correspond to preferred names of acids, and carboxylic acids that are not substitutable generate nonsubstitutable aldehydes;
>
> (3) by using the prefixes ‘oxo’, denoting $\ce{=O}$, or ‘formyl-’, denoting the substituent group $\ce{-CHO}$.

In particular,

> **P-66.6.1.1.3** The suffix ‘carbaldehyde’ is used when the $\ce{-CHO}$ group is attached to a carbon atom of a ring or ring system, or to a heteroatom.

For example, ‘cyclohexanecarbaldehyde’ is a PIN.

[image: cyclohexanecarbaldehyde]

However, according to **P-66.6.1.2.1,** the PIN for the compound given in the question is ‘benzaldehyde’. (This name is analogous to the preferred name of the corresponding acid ‘benzoic acid’, see **P-66.6.1** (2) above.)

[image: benzaldehyde]

Nevertheless, according to **P-66.6.1.2.2,** the PINs for phthalaldehyde and terephthalaldehyde are the systematic names ‘benzene-1,2-dicarbaldehyde’ and ‘benzene-1,4-dicarbaldehyde’, respectively. (These names are analogous to the preferred names of the corresponding acids ‘benzene-1,2-dicarboxylic acid’ [not ‘phthalic acid’] and ‘benzene-1,4-dicarboxylic acid’ [not ‘terephthalic acid’], respectively.)

[image: benzene-1,2-dicarbaldehyde]   [image: benzene-1,4-dicarbaldehyde]