# I need the diagram of "cyclobutanal"

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I doubted whether I can say cyclobutanal or not. Im confused and didn't found my answer anywhere

Comment: There simply cannot be an aldehyde functional group inside a cyclobutane ring.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19868/when-is-the-carbaldehyde-suffix-correct/19869

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have correct names for related alcohols butanol (e.g. **butan-1-ol**) and **cyclobutanol**. Here the -ol suffix means $\ce{-OH}$ group *attached* to the carbon atom.

In **butanal** ($\ce{CH3CH2CH2CHO}$), suffix **-al** means not just $\ce{=O}$ group (oxo group), but entire $\ce{-CHO}$ which already contains carbon, which is *included* in the counting and numbering. (No locant is needed, because the aldehyde group can be only at the terminal carbon, 1.) If you want to name C-1 to C-4 cyclized butanal, its correct name is **cyclobutanone**.

Now, it's impossible for cyclic compound to contain aldehyde group in the cycle. For $\ce{-CHO}$ group *attached* (not included) to the parent cycle, suffix **-carbaldehyde** is used, therefore names ***“cyclobutanal”*** or ***“cyclobutan-1-al”*** are wrong, correct is **cyclobutanecarbaldehyde**.

[image: Fig.1]

Comment: Thankyou mykhal, I've cleared my doubt in nomenclature in both the classroom and here also with this wonderful explanation, thanks alot. Well, is there any more exceptions in naming like this in aldehydes . ?

Answer (score 1):

It's cyclobutanecarboxaldehyde (or cyclobutanecarbaldehyde). I found for you nice little picture of this guy.

[image]

Comment: Correct name is cyclobutanecarbaldehyde. There's an instance of "…carboxaldehyde" name in latest IUPAC nomenclature book, but it's a mistake fixed in the ERRATA.

Comment: Well, here's my real question guys, can't I write it like cyclobutan-1-al. It seems all good with keeping rules in mind , still my teacher got it wrong.

Comment: @VishalKumar No, according to the rules, this name does not make sense.